# Redirecting output from gdb when using --args options

Tags: gdb

I am running gdb in a script:
gdb -tui -x     gdb.txt --args exe - -cdis ${CDIS} -zzinfo ${ZZINFO}
and in gdb.txt
run &> gdbsession_output.log

It seemed to work, but then I discovered that argc/argv just contain one argument (the program).

Redirecting on the command-line doesnt work either.  How can I do this?

More complete:
gdb -tui -x /users/bat/nb/gdb.txt --args /apps/atlas/${LIBPRONTO}/bin/${ES_NAME} -zzinfo ${ZZINFO}

run &> /apps/atlas/runtime/logs/gdbsession_output.log

Comment: Actually 
tty gdbsession_output.log
then
run
does this.
(commandline would be better though)

Comment: this did the magic. Thanks! I agree that a command line option would have been better.